# C Programming: How do I insert a number into an array such that each digit of the number goes into each field of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, largenumber

I need to put a 1000 digit number and process each digit of it. Hence I wish to split the number into single digits and put them into each of the fields of an array of size 1000. How can I do this using C programming?

EDIT: I have been working on Project Euler question 8. I know what I have to do: put each of the digits into an array and use a sliding window to find the largest product. But I am not sure about the implementation. I have searched for other answers but I am afraid all of them are in any language other than C and seem easy. I wanted to implement the same in C so asking the forum.

Comment: There are a lot of these questions and answers already on SO, this one for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962341/how-do-i-turn-an-integer-into-an-array-of-digits-without-using-strings

Comment: What is the datatype of your 1000 digit number?

Comment: Did you try `populate_array_with_digit_splits(array, value);`? Note that you may have to write that function.

Comment: The reason I ask about the datatype of your number, is that, in all likelihood, it already is in some string form, in which case it would be super easy to do what you want.  So is your number a numeric or a string type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAX_NUMS 5  // change me to 1000
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char numberString[ MAX_NUMS + 1 ];
    int  numberNumeric [ MAX_NUMS ];
    printf("Enter number ");
    scanf("%s",numberString);
    for ( int i=0; i < MAX_NUMS; ++i)
    {
        printf("converting %c\n",numberString[i]);
        numberNumeric[i] = (numberString[i] - 0x30);  // convert ascii to integer
    }

    // Your array of 1-digit numbers
   for ( int i=0; i < MAX_NUMS; ++i)
   {
     printf("%i ",numberNumeric[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```